# How to fetch last select statements result set?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that looks like below Pseudo:

```
create procedure composite(IN a varchar(255),IN b varchar(255),IN c datetime,IN d datetime)
begin
DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE count float;
SET str = '';
SET str = CONCAT("aname like '%",a,"%' "," and bname ='",b,"' ");
set @comp = CONCAT("SELECT * from abc where ",str, "GROUP BY qname");
PREPARE stmt FROM @comp;
EXECUTE stmt;
set count = found_rows();
SET STR1 = CONCAT("aname like '%",a,"%' "," and bname ='",b,"' ");
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT * from xyz",str,"GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(abcdate)),qname");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
end//
```

When I execute this i get 2 result-sets as output i.e. from executing 2 select statement. I want the output of only last select. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: simply remove the first EXECUTE stmt;

Comment: As from the above code, i am executing set count = found_rows(); that will get the number of rows returned from 1st Execute and hence I cannot remove.

Comment: Added a work around for the issue sourced the first select result to the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Do not quite understand what you want to do. I imagine that the stored procedure is not complete.

Is it really necessary to use prepared statements in this case? Do you need to `count` as float?

Maybe something like this might be useful:

```sql
...
DECLARE count BIGINT UNSIGNED;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count /* Here you can use a user variable (@count) and avoiding the local variable (count) */
FROM (
    SELECT 0
    FROM abc
    WHERE aname LIKE CONCAT('%', a, '%') AND bname = b
    GROUP BY qname
) der;

SELECT aname, bname, qname
FROM xyz
WHERE aname LIKE CONCAT('%', a, '%') AND bname = b
GROUP BY qname;
...
```

The first statement will store the number of rows in the local variable `count` and will not return the dataset. Beware of variable names and reserved words, in this case `count` is allowed, but read [9.3. Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in the documentation.